# Gnu make exclusive OR (kinda) in prerequistires list?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a pattern rule like this:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%/*.c
    $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%.c OR $(SOURCES_DIR)/%/*.c
    $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
```

Where `OR` means if there the target `$(BIN_DIR)/progname` requsted, first look for `$(SOURCEDS_DIR)/progname.c` and it will be the only prerequisite. If there is no such file, prerequisites list will be `$(SOURCES_DIR)/progname/*.c` as it is now in the original rule? Maybe some other way to achieve this behaviour?

Full Makefile (tests ommited as irrelevant):

```
SOURCES_DIR         = src
INCLUDE_DIR         = $(SOURCES_DIR)/include
OBJECTS_DIR         = build
BIN_DIR             = bin
LIB_DIR             = lib

INCLUDE_FLAGS = -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
CFLAGS=-g --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -O2 $(INCLUDE_FLAGS)
LDLIBS=-ldl -lm $(OPTLIBS) 
LIB_SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/lib*)
BIN_SOURCES=$(filter-out $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(LIB_SOURCES),\
              $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/*)))
BINS=$(addprefix $(BIN_DIR)/, $(notdir $(BIN_SOURCES)))
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,\
        $(subst $(SOURCES_DIR),$(OBJECTS_DIR),\
        $(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/lib**/*.c)))
LIBS=$(addsuffix .a, $(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)/, $(notdir $(LIB_SOURCES))))

SO_LIBS=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(LIBS))

all: $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(SO_LIBS) $(BINS)

$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o: CFLAGS+= -fPIC
$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%*
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCES_DIR)/$*.c -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(LIB_DIR)/%.a: $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $(OBJECTS_DIR)/$*/*.o
    ranlib $@

$(LIB_DIR)/%.so: $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -shared $(OBJECTS_DIR)/$*/*.o -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

# the rule i'm talking about
$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%/*.c
    $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Confession: tl;dr</sup>

> Is it possible to do something like:
>
> ```makefile
> $(BIN_DIR)/%: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%.c OR $(SOURCES_DIR)/%/*.c
>     $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
> ```

You can do it by declaring the pattern rule twice.
Put the recipe in a macro to avoid writing that twice.

```makefile
define recipe
    $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
endef

$(BIN_DIR)/%: ${SOURCES_DIR}/%.c
    $(recipe)

$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%/*.c
    $(recipe)
```

Ok, but don't do this.
Pattern rules are an ugly hack IMHO—I don't like the ambiguity.
Different *make* versions do different things.
(Wildcards aren't much better, but I won't comment further here.)
It always feels cleaner to write explicitly what you want.
You can still use patterns,
but use *static pattern rules* by explicitly listing the targets that the patterns apply to.

```makefile
recipe = $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)

single-source-targets := $(addprefix ${BIN_DIR}/,counter filter)# for example
multi-source-targets := $(addprefix ${BIN_DIR}/,engine database)

${single-source-targets}: ${BIN_DIR}/%: ${SOURCES_DIR}/%.c ; $(recipe)
${multi-source-targets}: ${BIN_DIR}/%: ${SOURCES_DIR}/%/*.c ; $(recipe)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to give a specific answer without the entire Makefile.

But since this is a question of two variable file paths: conditional search directories (`$(SOURCES_DIR)` or `$(SOURCES_DIR)/progname`), AND conditional files to search for (`$(SOURCES_DIR)/progname.c` or `$(SOURCEDS_DIR)/progname/*.c`), the solution is more complicated than a simple makefile rule.

The best way I can think of is to use conditionals to set the dependency directory and filename as shown below.

```
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/progname.c)","")
    DEPS = $(SOURCES_DIR)/progname.c
else 
    DEPS = $(SOURCES_DIR)/progname/*.c
endif   

$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $? $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Well all the point is to get ot working wit a lot of files like `$(SOURCES_DIR)/*.c` and there can be different files i.e. `$(SOURCES_DIR)/prog1.c $(SOURCES_DIR)/prog2.c $(SOURCES_DIR)/prog3/{foo.c,main.c}` And i don't think `ifneq`  will work for this, because of need to specify a filename. I will add full Makefile in the original question now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got what i want, even though i don't really like how I did this, so any other variants are appritiated. It's difficult to build prerequisites list conditionally, so i decided to use different targets, and then just copy files where i wanted. This did the job, but still not very pretty. I just added following lines to the `Makefile`:

```
ONEFILERS_SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SOURCES_DIR)/*.c)
ONEFILERS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(subst $(SOURCES_DIR),$(ONEFILERS_TMP),\
          $(ONEFILERS_SOURCES)))

$(ONEFILERS_TMP)/%: $(SOURCES_DIR)/%.c $(SHARED_INCLUDES)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
    @install $@ $(BIN_DIR)
```

Any better solutions are welcome.